# My React button click logs twice for every single click

Tags: reactjs

[Image of my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSjng.png)

Whenever I click on the button in my child Component, it logs twice for every single click. I discovered this by simply adding a console.log(this.props) in my child components render function. This is the code below

Parent Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,

    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter onClick={this.handleClick} value={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counters;
```

Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <span className="badge badge-secondary">{this.props.value}</span>
        <button
          onClick={this.props.onClick}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-primary m-2"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: Add your code, so we can help you.

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow. you need to post the code for us to help you! how else could we tell what the issue is?

Comment: Just for check, can you change `onClick` prop naming into something else like `handleClick` or so?

Comment: I very much doubt the click handler is being called twice. I think it's more likely that the state update causes a re-render, and since your `console.log()` is in the `render` function the props are simply logged twice. How many logs do you see if you move the `console.log()` to the `handleClick` function?

Comment: @rickdenhaan It doesn't log twice when i place it in the handleClick function, but why would the render function render twice tho

Comment: I finally found the issue in index.js,  my counters component was wrapped with <React.StrictMode>.  After removing it as recommended by @HMR, the re rendering stopped.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your app is wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>` that can cause render functions, or functional components to be called multiple times for debugging purposes.